# Where to calculate distance from current location Swift 3 UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

OK, so I was having a bit of a problem with a tableview taking ages to load data from a Firebase DB.  I tracked it down to a calculation I was doing in the struct that defines the variables for the tableview.  in my DB is lat and long values, and I was calculating the distance from current location in the struct.  This had the effect of slowing the population of the tableview to around 15 seconds.  Once I disabled this calculation the tableview populates almost instantly.

So my question is where should I do the calculation?  I have a label on my tableview cells that should display the distance from your current location.  I have temporarily set this to a static value.  But I need it to calculate.

I have a struct which initialises the fields used throughout the app, I have a custom cell class which assigns the values to the various elements on the cell, and I have a ViewController where the code is for the tableView.

Where should the calulation be done and still populate the label in the cell?

Comment: Maybe you can move your calculation code into another thread? When the result is calculated you could add it to your cell label ?

Comment: so would i run something like this?  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    calculation here

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
    }
}


where would i put it? in the struct where the calculation was before or somewhere else

Comment: Yeah something like this! I would put it where you call your calculation method so in your cellForRow in table view, I would put something like 
`dispatch{... cell.distance.text = *result* }`